# Efficient algorithm for generating a Metro-like gallery layout

Tags: algorithm, math

How the layout looks:

[image: Layout]

Tiles have different sizes but they snap to an invisible grid.

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm that allows me to place a variable number of images with variable natural sizes into such a layout and:

- don't leave gaps
- don't leave any images out
- leave no cropping (not sure if possible), or crop as little as possible from the image

For example, the best algorithm for this kind of layout:

[image: Rows]

Is to scale images one by one so they fit into the desired maximum row height. Stop when enough images fill a row. Then scale down the entire row until the images fit perfectly. No cropping, missing images or re-ordering here.

For the metro layout, my idea is takes each image and resize it just enough to snap to the grid. Say an image is 644x452 and the smallest grid block is 40x40, then the image is resized to 626x440 (440 is the closest snapping point to 452), then cropped to 440x440. But I don't have a good idea on how would I place them in the grid and fill all gaps.

Comment: how about aspect ratio?

Comment: The "no cropping" part is impossible